# Why some access modes in fopen() throw a PHP warning on my new server?

Tags: php, fopen, php-8

I am doing a PHP script migration from **php 5.6.40** (Apache 2.2.15 CentOS 6.10 server) to **php 8.0.1** (Apache 2.4.37 CentOS 8.3).

I have troubles with `fopen()` function which throws a warning according to the mode option.
I searched the web without finding similar problem...

On each server, I have the same context and the same permissions :

```
$ pwd
/export/php/logs/aita
$ ll
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache     33 27 janv. 15:30 testFopen.txt
```

My test-script is very simple, it cheks all fopen modes :

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'r');  // line 2
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'r+'); // line 3
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'w');  // line 4
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'w+'); // line 5
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'a');  // line 6
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'a+'); // line 7
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'x');  // line 8
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'x+'); // line 9
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'c');  // line 10
$handle = fopen("/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt", 'c+'); // line 11
```

When running this script, I obtain :

On my old server PHP 5.6.40

```
[error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): failed to open stream: File exists in /export/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 8
[error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): failed to open stream: File exists in /export/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 9
```

Thoses warnings are logicals (file exists and exclusion).

On my new server PHP 8.0.1

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 37251:tid xxxx] [client x.x.x.x:x] AH01071: Got error '
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 3
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 4
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 5
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): Failed to open stream: File exists in /var/www/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 8
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): Failed to open stream: File exists in /var/www/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 9
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 10
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/export/php/logs/aita/testFopen.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/aita_dev/testFopen.php on line 11'
```

Warnings from lines 8 and 9 make sense here too.

Modes r+, w[+] and c[+] generate the "permission denied" warning.

Modes r, a[+] works well, without warnings.

I am able to read the file with "r" option.
I am able to write the file with "a" and "a+" options so it doesn't seem like a permission problem.

I would like to understand and not have to correct all the fopen() of my applications...

Comment: My guess is that this isn't a change in PHP itself, but some other difference between the servers - some extended permission system is ensuring that the log-file is append-only.

Comment: yes, it seems to be a system problem !
Our system engineer just tells me that it could be due to SELinux (Security-Enhanced Linux). I'm testing with differents SELinux settings

Answer (score 1):

The administrator in charge of the servers has **lowered the alert level of SELinux** (Security-Enhanced Linux) and everything is now functioning normally.

The system was set up to only allow read/append on files for the Apache user as suggested by IMSoP